# how to properly get data from an XML SOAP response in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm able to access part of the XML record but the problem is the returned value is presented in this format below:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 
1234567
)
```

And if I use inspect element this is what it shows:

```
<xx>
   <yy>
      <a>1</a>
      <b>2</b>
      <c>3</c>
      <d>4</d>
   </yy>
   <zz Type="type">
      <e>5</e>
      <f>6</f>
      <g>
         <h>7</h>
      </g>
   </zz>
</xx>
```

SOAP XML Response: (The actual SOAP response have < and > converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` I just changed it here to make it more readable)

```
<s:envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:body>
<processrequestresponse xmlns="http://zzz.org/">
<processrequestresult>
<xx>
   <yy>
      <a>1</a>
      <b>2</b>
      <c>3</c>
      <d>4</d>
   </yy>
   <zz Type="type">
      <e>5</e>
      <f>6</f>
      <g>
         <h>7</h>
      </g>
   </zz>
</xx>
</processrequestresult>
</processrequestresponse>
</s:body>
</s:envelope>
```

Code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$data    = $xml->xpath("//s:Body/*")[0];
        $details = $data->children("http://zzz.org/");
        $test    = $details->ProcessRequestResult[0];
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($test);
```

So my question is how do I access the values for a,b,c,d,e,f, and g individually?

Comment: Is your expected output simply 1 through 7, in your example? If not, please edit the question and add the exact expected output.

Comment: @JackFleeting it is, so I only need to get access to the data stored in <a> or <b> or <c> etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$data = $xml->xpath('//*//text()');

foreach ($data as $datum) {
    if (strlen(trim($datum))>0)
    echo trim($datum)."\n\r";
}
```

Output should be 1 through 7.

Comment: thanks, will give this a try. do you by chance know what that part of the code is called when it does that? i.e showing numbers but inspect element shows it's actually more?

Comment: it works only if I manually set the XML into a variable, but if I try to use the response from the SOAP request it doesn't work. Maybe because the SOAP response has transformed < and > to "&lt;" and "&gt;"?

Comment: I got it working by doing html_entity_decode on the response first. thank you for this! but can you explain the code more so that I can learn more about dealing with XML in the future?

Comment: @magicianiam The secret sauce here is getting to know xpath inside out (note that php, unfortunately, supports only xpath 1.0, but it doesn't hurt to get to know xpath all the way up to version 3.1). In this particular case, the xpath expression is super simple - translated to English it means "select all nodes and if the node has a text child, select that"). Another thing to note is the fact that SOAP uses namespaces (which we didn't use in this case), so when you read up on xpath, you should pay particular attention to that aspect.